# Shortening Border of a Grid

Tags: c#, uwp

I want to set the border of a grid in a way that it's only on the top of it (this is what I've managed to do) and that it's only in the center of the top (I mean it starts about 30px from the left edge and ends also 30px from the end)
The Code I use for generating Grid (in the .cs file):

```
Grid NewGrid = new Grid()
{
     Height = 90,
     Padding = new Thickness { Left = 0, Right = 0, Top = 0, Bottom = 0 },
     BorderThickness = new Thickness { Left = 0, Top = 1, Right = 0, Bottom = 0 },
     BorderBrush = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black),
};
```

The image of what I want to achieve: 
[image]

where the gray color is no border and the black is a visible solid border...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do this with `Grid.BorderBrush` and `Grid.BorderThickness`; the border always extends to the corners of the element.

Just use a `Rectangle` in the first row of the Grid to achieve the border you want:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <!-- The first row is for the border only -->
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>

        <!-- Use additional rows as your layout dictates -->
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!-- The border element in the first row -->
    <Rectangle Margin="50,0" Fill="Black" Height="2"/>

    <!-- The main content of the Grid in subsequent rows -->
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Content="Example 1"/>
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Content="Example 2"/>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, this is exactly what I wanted.

Answer (score 0):

i think the best approach would be set no border on the Grid, but overlay a Line on top of the grid with the computed width like...

```
Line newLine = new Line();
{
    line1.X2 = NewGrid.Width -60;
}
```